# Adding Fade in when Hovering over Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to add a slight fade in/fade out, when hovering over items here
http://jsfiddle.net/7vKFN/

Was wondering whats the best way to do this using jquery

```
 var $container = $("#color-container"),
        $description = $(".color-description", $container).hide(),
        $prev;

    $(".color-units li", $container).mouseenter(function() {
        if ($prev)
           $description.eq( $prev.removeClass("active").index() ).hide();
        $description.eq( ($prev = $(this).addClass("active")).index() ).show();
    }).eq(0).mouseenter();
```

Comment: What are you trying to fade? The `li` elements that are hovered, or the changed text?

Comment: I would ideally like to add a very slight fade to both, because right now its very jarring when the content is replaced being it happens almost immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

http://jsfiddle.net/7vKFN/1/

```
$(".color-units li", $container).mouseenter(function() {
    if ($prev)
       $description.eq( $prev.removeClass("active").index() ).hide();
    $description.eq( ($prev = $(this).addClass("active")).index() ).fadeIn("slow", function() {
    // Animation complete
  })

}).eq(0).mouseenter();
```